# Double completed date fields in Activity fields

Tags: reporting, activities, custom-activity, sales

I have strange thing on my salesforce, in Activity Custom Fields section there is only one "Completed Date" field
[image]

but there are 2 same completed date fields in my custom report type with Primary Object "Activities"

[image]

Somehow it creates inconsistency in between field as shown in below image
[image]

Can someone help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Activity object has CompletedDate field (Label: **Complete Date**, API Name: **CompleteDateTime**, Data Type: **Date/Time**).

In your report, the complete date with time information is standard field and the one without time information is your custom field which is **CompletedDate__c**.

Hope this helps.